# Types of inline and block elements in html5

Tags: html

What are the different types of inline and block elements in html5

I am confused between the different types of inline and block elements in html5

Comment: Are you asking about sth like “inline-block”? Block is block and Inline is online, there are no types. Inline-block is the combination of them, inline-flex and more is also possible.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any.

---

HTML 4.x uses [`%block`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#block) and [`%inline`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#inline) to categorize most elements in the specification. This is so the DTD can specify which elements are allowed as children of which other elements.

HTML 5 does not as it goes into much more detail about what elements are allowed where using [categories](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#content-categories) — like flow and phrasing — and more complex rules like "[Content model:
Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant and no descendant with the tabindex attribute specified.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element)" instead.

---

Meanwhile CSS's [`display` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) which (in [version 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#display)) supported only four values (`block`, `inline`, `list-item`, and `none`) — so most HTML elements (by default) displayed as either block or inline — now has significantly more values, some of which can be combined (like `display: inline flow-root`).

---

In the 1990s block and inline were useful categories for describing elements. Today, and in HTML 5, they are not.